# Company suggests another position after being rejected - how to pivot my application?

Tags: interviewing, applications, networking, rejection

I applied to the engineering division in a company and was rejected, but they suggested that a front-end developer role in the client services division would be a better fit. Additionally, I have a recommendation from a friend who is a junior/mid-level developer in the client services division and has provided a personal reference. Upon receiving the rejection email, the engineering manager recommended that I follow up with "Joe" (Client Services Director) and "Pam" (Talent/Recruiting Director).

I responded by expressing my interest in the client services division and briefly described my interests in the client-facing services. All communication was done through their job applicant system, so Joe, Pam, my friend, and the engineering director are all cc'd on the email. It's been two days and I haven't heard back, and I wonder what else I can do to follow up.

Should I send a cover letter to Joe and Pam, detailing how I can fit with the client services division? I have some knowledge about the position after talking with my friend, and he recommended that I express my interest in client empathy and client facing services as I pivot my application. My original application (to the engineering division) didn't outline my client services skills.

The company does exciting work and I am new to the industry and trying to get my foot in the door. I am also dedicated to my craft and I want to express my enthusiasm and motivation to work there. I see this position as a step forward and in a couple years I may be able to move into an deeper engineering role. Any suggestions on how to express this, or should I continue waiting for them to follow up with me? My friend has already put in a good word for me, and I don't want to over-step his offers to help, but he may also be able to help me communicate my interest to their client services team.

Comment: Would like this question better if you renamed "Joe" to "Jim"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your email service indicates that your mails were successfully received, you can wait a few more days to follow up on your communication.

Did you mention in your cover letter to Joe and Pam that you interviewed with the engineering manager and that although he passed you over, he recommended that you apply to the client services division? Because if you did, you are making it less likely that Joe and Pam are going to sit on your application.

I'd say wait several more days and if Joe and Pam show no sign of life, resend the application, making sure that you mention the engineering director's recommendation in your cover letter. And that you target your cover letter to substantiate your interest and fit in the client services division.

Comment: I don't think I was clear about the cover letter, as I only sent a cover letter to the engineering hiring manager. Perhaps I should send another one to Joe and Pam? The only thing seen by Joe and Pam is the email correspondence between the engineering division manager and myself, where Joe and Pam were recently cc'd. In that email, I expressed my desire to join the client services division, but I did not go in depth. Perhaps I should send a formal cover letter to Joe and Pam soon! Should I send them a new, tailored resume as well? I'm worried that I may come across as too amorphous.

Comment: @mrNiceGuy You can get away with a one-size-fits-all resume as long as your cover letter is properly tailored and customized. Which in this case, it isn't. It's a different position with a different group of people who don't know you from Adam and who don't know Adam from a hole in the ground. Give your application to the position your full seriousness, attention and respect. Don't get sloppy.